# Is there a way for a process simulation in AnyLogic to generate and export event logs?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, process-mining

I could not find a way to generate a process mining suitable XES-event log based on an AnyLogic simulation of a process. If anyone knows if this is possible and how to do it, I would much appreciate it (very new to AnyLogic so it might just be user error).

Thank you

Comment: AnyLogic does generate logs by default. Check the database part. You can export them

Comment: If you need to write in some specific format, either code that yourself or use a Java library that would do the format you need...